# Utilizing roll functions with data.table

Tags: r, data.table, vectorization

I'm having problems specifically applying functions from the `roll` package using `data.table`. I'm attempting to calculate rolling metrics on column `DT$obs` for each group `DT$group`. I'm able to calculate rolling metrics using the `zoo` package, but I'd like to use some of the additional arguments in `roll` package functions.

Demo of the error is below.

```
require(data.table)
require(zoo)
require(roll)


# Fabricated Data:
DT <- data.table(group = rep(c("A", "B"), each = 20), obs = runif(40, min = 0, max = 100))


# Calculate a rolling sum (this is working properly)
DT[, RollingSum := lapply(.SD, function(x) zoo::rollsumr(x, k = 5, fill = NA)), by = "group", .SDcols = "obs"]


# Attempt to calculate a rolling z-score (this throws me an error)
DT[, RollingZScore := lapply(.SD, function(x) roll::roll_scale(as.matrix(x), width = 10, min_obs = 5)), by = "group", .SDcols = "obs"]
```

[image]

I can't figure out what's different about the `zoo` function and the `roll` function. They each return numeric vectors. Any guidance appreciated.

Comment: Fwiw, if it needs a matrix input, it's probably not a good fit with data.table. The problem you're seeing here seems to be because the result is a 20x1 matrix, not a vector (try `DT[, str(roll::roll_scale(as.matrix(obs), width = 10, min_obs = 5)), by = "group"]`), just as the error says: "All items in j=list(...) should be atomic vectors or lists."

Comment: To fix the problem Frank describes, use `as.vector` on the output of `roll_scale`

Comment: @Renu `as.vector` works. Thanks! If you post it, I will accept.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @Frank describes, the problem is that the result of `roll_scale` (and thus each element of `lapply` output) is a matrix. You can either use `sapply` instead of `lapply`, or put `as.vector` in your function definition.

```
DT[, RollingZScore := sapply(.SD, 
                             function(x) roll::roll_scale(as.matrix(x), width = 10, min_obs = 5)), 
   by = "group", .SDcols = "obs"]
```

or

```
DT[, RollingZScore := lapply(.SD, 
                              function(x) as.vector(roll::roll_scale(as.matrix(x), width = 10, min_obs = 5))), 
    by = "group", .SDcols = "obs"]
```

Answer (score 1):

This can be done with `rollapplyr` by simply defining a function that returns `NA` if the input has fewer than 5 elements:

```
Scale <- function(x) if (length(x) < 5) NA else tail(scale(x), 1)
DT[, rollingScore := rollapplyr(obs, 10, Scale, partial = TRUE), by = "group"]
```